# ipython-notebook: print rmagic plots as svg

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, rpy2

I use the following code fragment to plot a pandas dataframe with ggplot in ipython notebook.

```
%%R -i data
plot = ggplot(data) + geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y))
print(plot)
```

The result is the expected plot in png format. I would like to have an svg image instead, but I just cannot figure out how this can be done.

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer to your own question--I just came looking and this was helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In previous versions of *rpy2* my proposed solution did not work. However with `rpy2-2.4.3` the following now works as expected:

```
%load_ext rpy2.ipython 
%R require(ggplot2)
%Rdevice svg
```

After setting up R, the plotting works as expected and the shown plot will be in svg format.

Create data as a pandas DataFrame in python:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({"x":[1,2,3], "y": [3,2,1]})
```

And finally do the plotting:

```
%%R -i data
plot = ggplot(data) + geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y))
print(plot)
```